# Server-Sent Events API - Default reconnection time

Tags: html, server-sent-events

I'm currently studying SSE's. In the w3 specifications it says:

> A reconnection time, in milliseconds. This must initially be a user-agent-defined value, probably in the region of a few seconds.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#concept-event-stream-reconnection-time

How I understand this is that each webbrowser has a default reconnection time, but I can't seem to find the exact values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the footnote on p.65 of Data Push Apps with HTML5 SSE:

> At the time of writing, it is 3 seconds in Chrome and Safari (see
>   core/page/EventSource.cpp in the WebKit or [Blink source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/5fcd859a37832978e0e504e7218fd910b7d20675/Source/core/page/EventSource.cpp)) and 5
>   seconds in Firefox (see [content/base/src/EventSource.cpp in the
>   Mozilla source code](https://github.com/rillian/firefox/blob/master/content/base/src/EventSource.cpp)).

(I just checked and those are still the current values.)